# Como ler arquivo .cap com C?

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um **pequeno programa em (C/C++)** para ler alguns dados de um arquivo .CAP (fornecido pelo TCPDUMP). Um bom exemplo seria WireShark, mas preciso de bem menos INFO.

Acontece que, esse .CAP parece ser escrito em HEXA e quando leio o dado ele vem "codificado".

Como tenho pouquíssima experiencia, **e tenho que aprender isso.**.. acho que não estou **sabendo fazer a pergunta**, então conto com a boa vontade dos amigos.

Sem contar que tenho, simplesmente me **perdido em um mar de links** na internet, que só causaram mais confusão.

**Explico:**
[Neste link se pode baixar o .CAP](http://tecnocubo.com.br/downloads/foruns/tcpdump_20160712_2300.cap), que eh aberto tranquilamente pelo WireShark, já meu código abaixo retorna "caracteres estranhos".

**como por exemplo:**

## ==> **revision: �ò�***

ou

### ==> ***header_pad: ò�***

Onde "revision", por exemplo deveria ser **12 HEXA**  ou se convertido **18 decimal**

- Bom, como sou um iniciante, tentei deixar o código o mais comentado possível.

Sendo que esse código pretende rodar em um terminal linux..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// #include <curses.h>

// テスト用フラグ => Test for the flag
int LOOP_ONCE = 1;

// WiFi取得情報構造体 => get information structure

// Radiotap Header
// 18bytes固定長（と思われる）=> fixed length (seems to be)
typedef struct WF_HEADER
{
    char header_revision[1];
  char header_pad[1];
  unsigned short int header_length;
  char present_flags[4];
  char flags[1];
  char data_rate[1];
  char channel_frequency[2];
  char channel_flags[2];
  char ssi_signal[1];
  char antenna[1];
  char rx_flags[2];
} wf_header_t;

// IEEE802.11 Probe Request （前半部分）=>  (first half)
// 24bytes固定長  =>  fixed length
typedef struct WF_PROBE1
{
  char frame_control_field[4];
  char receiver_address[6];
  char transmitter_address[6];
  char bbs_id[6];
  char numbers[2];
} wf_probe1_t;

// IEEE802.11 Probe Request（後半部分）=>  (the latter part)
// 4bytes固定長 => fixed length
typedef struct WF_PROBE2
{
  char frame_check_sequence[4];
} wf_probe2_t;

// IEEE802.11 wireless LAN management frame（繰り返しヘッダー） => (repeat header)
// 2bytes
typedef struct WF_MANAGE_HEADER
{
  char tag_number[1];
  char tag_length[1];
} wf_manage_header_t;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char read_fname[30]; //読み込みファイル名                => read file name
  int read_fb;         //読み込みファイルバンドル           => read file bundle
  wf_header_t *wfh;    //WiFiデータ読み込み構造体のポインタ  => pointer of WiFi data read structure
  int read_size;       //読み込みファイルサイズ             => read file size
  int wfh_size;        // Wifiデータ構造体のサイズ          => Wifi data structure; int wfh_size

  /* WiFiデータ読み込み構造体の領域確保      =>   Area of ​​WiFi data read structure ensure */
  wfh_size = sizeof(wf_header_t);
  wfh = calloc(1, wfh_size);

  /* ループ実行 */ 
  /* Loop execution */
  while (1) {
    /* ファイルの存在を監視する         =>  To monitor the presence of the file */
    /* 読み込みファイル名取得      =>  Read file name acquisition */
    if (1) {

        system("clear");

        // テスト用プログラム            =>  Test program
      fprintf(stdout, "読み込みファイル名を入力してください。\n"); // Please enter the reading file name 
      scanf("%s", read_fname);
      fprintf(stdout, "ファイル名:%s\n", read_fname);         //file name:
    } else {
      // 次のファイル名を取得するような仕組み   =>  Like to get the following file name mechanism


    }
    /* ファイルオープン処理     =>  Seek to the data top position */
    read_fb = open(read_fname, O_RDONLY);
    if (read_fb == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイルオープンに失敗しました。\n"); //Failed to open file
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイル名：%s\n", read_fname);    //file name
      return -1;
    }

    /* データ先頭位置までシークする                           =>  Seek to the data top position * /
    /* 前ファイルの続きである場合は、そのまま残サイズを読み込む    => Case is a continuation of the previous file, as it is read in the remaining size */

    read_size = read(read_fb, wfh, wfh_size);
    if (read_size == -1) {
      /* ファイル読み込み失敗       =>     File read failure */
      free(wfh); 
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイル読み込みに失敗しました。\n");  //failed to file read
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイル名：%s\n", read_fname);    //file name
      return -1;
    } else if (read_size == wfh_size) {
      fprintf(stdout, "====================================\n");
      fprintf(stdout, "revision: %s \n", wfh->header_revision);
      fprintf(stdout, "header_pad: %s \n", wfh->header_pad);
      fprintf(stdout, "present_flags: %s \n", wfh->present_flags);
      fprintf(stdout, "flags: %s \n", wfh->flags);
      fprintf(stdout, "data_rate: %s \n", wfh->data_rate);
      fprintf(stdout, "channel_frequency: %s \n", wfh->channel_frequency);
      fprintf(stdout, "channel_flags: %s \n", wfh->channel_flags);
      fprintf(stdout, "ssi_signal: %s \n", wfh->ssi_signal);
      fprintf(stdout, "antenna: %s \n", wfh->antenna);
      fprintf(stdout, "rx_flags: %s \n", wfh->rx_flags);
      fprintf(stdout, "====================================\n");



    } else {
      /* 残りサイズを読み込み、次のファイルへ進む    => Read the remaining size, advance to the next file */


    }


    /* 終了処理   End processing */
    if (close(read_fb) != -1) {
      // ファイルクローズに成功したので、バックアップフォルダへ移動させる
      // Since successful file close, move to the backup folder

    } else {
      free(wfh); 
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイルクローズに失敗しました。\n"); // file close failed 
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイル名：%s\n", read_fname);    // file name
      return -1;
    }
    /* ループ終了判定    =>    Loop termination determination */
    if (LOOP_ONCE == 1) {
      free(wfh); 
      fprintf(stdout, "終了しました。\n"); // was completed
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que processar o arquivo .cap de acordo com seu layout, que está documentado, por exemplo, aqui:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat

A não ser que você *realmente* tenha necessidade de escrever um programa para isso, o melhor seria filtrar a saída do próprio tcpdump, ou do wireshark, etc.

Comment: Valeu muito! esse material eh novo pra mim! vou estudar! TENHO que aprender isso e sim, vou ter que programar pra pegar APENAS algumas infos...  e como bom novato.. tenho  apanhado horrores!  Obrigado pela dica! não eh todo mundo que tem "saco" pra  aturar a gente.. os noobs !!

Comment: **Estou tendo bastante dificuldade** em saber como o pcap/pcap.h funciona... como chamar suas funções... **ou seja** como pegar aqueles componentes que preciso no site não achei muitos exemplos...

**como o item :** Data Rate: ou SSI Signal: entre outros...

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem exemplos de códigos em C usando a biblioteca pcap/pcap.h...

Claro que **já procurei no google**, mas a impressão que tive eh que os artigos que encontrei não sabiam muito bem do que estavam falando.

**Obrigado.**

Comment: Alguns exemplos que achei: **(1)** http://www.cnblogs.com/xiangshancuizhu/archive/2012/10/14/2723654.html. **(2)** http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html. **(3)** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999538/read-from-a-pcap-file-and-print-out-ip-addresses-and-port-numbers-in-c-but-my-r **(4)** http://vichargrave.com/develop-a-packet-sniffer-with-libpcap/ **(5)** e aqui estão as perguntas sobre pcap no SO em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pcap+c%2B%2B

Comment: valeu muito !!  estudando!