# Exemplos de uso da biblioteca pcap/pcap.h para programacao em C

Tags: c

[No post anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152194/como-ler-arquivo-cap-com-c), **eu procurava saber como ler corretamente** um caractere HEXA, (por acaso era a partir de um arquivo .PCAP)...
O qual ja foi resolvido!

**MAS agora, o proximo passo ja eh outro**: Preciso "saber interpretar" os dados obtidos

**LOGO  pergunto:**
Estou trabalhando com arquivos do TCPDUMP, onde minha proposta eh "decompor" arquivos .CAP para .CSV....

MAS preciso escolher apenas os componentes daquele **file.cap**, que serao importantes.

Mas estou tendo bastante dificuldade em saber como o pcap/pcap.h funciona...  como chamar suas funções...  ou seja como pegar aqueles componentes que preciso [no site não achei muitos exemplos](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html#lbAO)...

por exemplo:
**Data Rate:**  ou  **SSI Signal:**   entre outros...

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem exemplos de códigos em C usando a biblioteca pcap/pcap.h...

Claro que já procurei no google, mas a impressão que tive eh que os artigos que encontrei não sabiam muito bem do que estavam falando.

Obrigado.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas extensão seria pcap e não cap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap

Comment: acho melhor ser respondida na outra

Comment: Ok, Por favor, como eu poderia fazer (ou refazer) essa pergunta na outra, pois nao consegui.... se voce me explicar eu apago esse post, e aceito a sua resposta la!  Obrigado!

Comment: soh peco que note bem que, naquele post eu estava com problemas de interpretar caracteres hexa, char, e var....

Comment: Editei o post, espero ter conseguido mostrar a diferença....